# Changing the reference by using pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the code below , the expected output is 1. But it comes out to be 2. How does the refrence change?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    int *ptr1 = &a, *ptr2 = &b, *ptr3 = &c;
    int **sptr = &ptr1; //-Ref
    *sptr = ptr2;
    printf("%d",*ptr1);
}
```

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: There are no references in your code - `&` means "address of" when applied to an expression.

Comment: "Why" ? Because you just coded it to be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    int *ptr1 = &a, *ptr2 = &b, *ptr3 = &c; 

    // ptr1 points to a 
    // ptr2 points to b



    int **sptr = &ptr1; //-Ref
    // *sptr points to ptr1 , that means **sptr points indirectly to a

    *sptr = ptr2; //this translates in ptr1 = ptr2, that means ptr1 points to what ptr2 pointed 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is include for? Where is return from main? If you put whole code, make it acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int *ptr1 = &a, *ptr2 = &b, *ptr3 = &c;
```

`ptr1`'s value is `a`'s address, `ptr2` value is `b`'s address.

```
int **sptr = &ptr1; // sptr has address of ptr1
```

As `sptr` is pointing to `ptr1` (it's value is `ptr1`'s address), by using `*sptr` we can alter the value of `ptr1`.

```
*sptr = ptr2; //here we are altering contents of sptr and value of ptr1.
```

So now `ptr1` points where `ptr2` does. To `b = 2`;